# Добавление символа в EditText

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-fragment, android-edittext

Есть EditText как сделать так, чтобы при вводе первого символа например 5 перед ним в EditText добавлялся символ "(", чтобы было "(5". Я заюзал для EditText TextWatcher и в beforeChanged проверяю длину слова и если она == 0, то пытаюсь добавить "(" в слову. Исходник

```
editNumberPhone.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (s.length() == 0){
                s = "(" + s;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                editNumberPhone.clearFocus();
                editNumberPhoneCodeCity.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Так же ранее задавался таким вопрос, вот один из вариантов решения вашей задачи.

```
public class PhoneNumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private boolean isFormatting;
    private boolean deletingHyphen;
    private int hyphenStart;
    private boolean deletingBackward;

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
        if (isFormatting)
            return;

        isFormatting = true;

        if (deletingHyphen && hyphenStart > 0) {
            if (deletingBackward) {
                if (hyphenStart - 1 < text.length()) {
                    text.delete(hyphenStart - 1, hyphenStart);
                }
            } else if (hyphenStart < text.length()) {
                text.delete(hyphenStart, hyphenStart + 1);
            }
        }

        if (text.length() == 2 || text.length() == 6 || text.length() == 10) {
            text.append(' ');
        }

        isFormatting = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (isFormatting)
            return;

        // Make sure user is deleting one char, without a selection
        final int selStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(s);
        final int selEnd = Selection.getSelectionEnd(s);
        if (s.length() > 1 // Can delete another character
                && count == 1 // Deleting only one character
                && after == 0 // Deleting
                && (s.charAt(start) == '-' || s.charAt(start) == ' ') // a hyphen
                && selStart == selEnd) { // no selection
            deletingHyphen = true;
            hyphenStart = start;
            // Check if the user is deleting forward or backward
            if (selStart == start + 1) {
                deletingBackward = true;
            } else {
                deletingBackward = false;
            }
        } else {
            deletingHyphen = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
    eTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTxt);
    eTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (before == 0 && start == 0){
                eTxt.setText("(" + s);
                eTxt.setSelection(eTxt.getText().length());
            }
        }
    });
```